# Не работает React Router, не переходит на страницу-компонент

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Код главной страницы

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import All from './All/All';
import Quiz from './Quiz/Quiz';
import Menu from './Menu/Menu';
import Second from './Second/Second';
import First from './First/First';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends Component {
    render () {
  return (
      <All>
      <Menu>
      </Menu>
      <Second/>
      <First nameMe="Вячеслав"/>

      <Route path='/' />
      <Route path='/first' component={First} />
      <Route path='/second' component={Second} />
      </All>
  );
}
}
```

Код 1 страницы

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './First.css';
import Special from '../Special/Special';

export default class First extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            main: 'mainer'
        }
    }
    back (event) {
         var first = document.querySelector('.mainer');
         var quiz = document.querySelector('.quiz');
         var menu = document.querySelector('.probir');
         quiz.style.display = 'block';
         menu.style.display = 'block';
         first.style.display = 'none';
         event.preventDefault();
    }
    render () {
        return(
            <div className={this.state.main}>
            <h2>Создатель этого приложения - {this.props.nameMe}</h2>
            <Special />
            <p>Some text</p>
            <button onClick={this.back} className="button" 
            id="but">Назад</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Код 2 страницы

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Second.css';

export default class Second extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            classInp1: 'input',
            classInp2: 'input'
        }
    }
    Hand() {
         this.setState({classInp1: 'input_active', classInp2: 'input_active' })
         console.log(this.testIn.value);
    };
    render () {
        async function send() {
            var value1 = document.getElementById('first').value;
            var value2 = document.getElementById('second').value;

            var response = await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
                body: JSON.stringify({value1, value2})
            });

            var result = await response.json();
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
        function back(event) {
             var second = document.querySelector('.main_active');
             var quiz = document.querySelector('.quiz');
             var all = document.querySelector('.All');
             var menu = document.querySelector('.probir');
             quiz.style.display = 'block';
             menu.style.display = 'block';
             second.style.display = 'none';
             event.preventDefault();
        }
        return (
            <div className="main">
            <div className="headline">Main headline</div>
            <div className="text">Some text!</div>
            <input className={this.state.classInp1} ref={(input) => this.testIn = input} id="first" placeholder="Введите ваше имя"></input>
            <input className={this.state.classInp2} id="second" placeholder="Введите вашу фамилию"></input>
            <button onClick={send} onMouseOver={this.Hand.bind(this)} className="button" id="but1">Отправить</button>
            <button onClick={back} className="button" id="but2">Назад</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Само меню

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Menu.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Second from '../Second/Second';
import First from '../First/First';

export default class Menu extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            VarButt: 'butt',
            VarNav: 'menu'
        }
    }
    Hand () {
        this.setState({VarNav: 'menu_active'});
    }
    Nav () {
        this.setState({VarNav: 'menu'});
    }
    render () {

        return (
            <div className="probir">
            <nav className={this.state.VarNav} onClick={this.Nav.bind(this)}>
            <Link to={{pathname: '/first'}}>first part<br></br>(Об авторе)</Link>
            <Link to={{pathname: '/second'}}>second part<br></br>(Ваши персоналии)</Link>
            </nav>
            <button onClick={this.Hand.bind(this)} className={this.state.VarButt}>Menu</button>
            {this.props.children}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

В чем проблема, в другом приложении все работает, но там ссылки на главной странице, а не в меню.

Comment: а Route обернуты в Router?

Comment: В моей другом приложении route тоже без обертки, там все работает, но всеравно попробую обернуть.

Comment: Славян Куприянов, еще оберни все Route в Switch и роуту который имеет path="/" задай аттрибут exact

Comment: Всеравно не выходит

Comment: а можешь это всё в codesandbox засунуть, чтобы рабочий пример можно было посмотреть?

Comment: ЧТО ЭТО???? `var first = document.querySelector('.mainer');`

Comment: класс 1 страницы - компонента.